# Application with Lucene.net on server

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I have a strange problem with my webapplication,
it works on local host but not on our Server

after reducing the code to a minimum there's a runtime error by declaring:

Dim directory As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory("\1[...]9\search\Start\luceneindex")

I also tried other paths like 127 or just  "luceneindex"

-I'm working with Visualstudio 08.
- the right asp.net version is declared on the server
-i "published" the website and put the whole file on the server
- i created a reference to the lucene.net.dll and its in the \bin file [at local host]
--> by putting the whole file on the server lucene.net dll is also there.
It's a IIS server

#### Update:

I just noticed, that even

```
Dim analyzer As StandardAnalyzer = New StandardAnalyzer()
```

doesn't work.

But on the server there is the lucene.net.dll and my project should have a reference on that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You path seems invalid due to unescaped '\' character. You can fix it by:

```
Dim directory As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory("\\1[...]9\\search\\Start\\luceneindex")
```

or

```
Dim directory As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(@"\1[...]9\search\Start\luceneindex")
```

or

by using Path.Combine() method.